# After all this handwringing, do i need a new roof really?

Tags: roofing, shingles

I finally nailed everything down with a contractor, shingle line, and approach and just yesterday I got the feedback that I may not need a new roof...yet. So, I'm asking the hivemind. I started this journey after the home buying inspector told me last year that I should do some repairs. We decided to wait to this year after being told then that it wasn't immediate. Roof is 17 years old

I have a decking nail pop on the shingles that would cost $1,000 from one quote. It doesn't appear to leak, though one contractor said it probably is. Then the flat roof needs some help---how much, I'm not sure. Again, 17 years old. I had always assumed it would be $3 grand in repairs (silicone the flat roof?) or so out of ~$8k to get a new roof, ergo just get the new roof now. But now am unsure.

Pics: https://imgur.com/gallery/NWMxvOS

Comment: The flat roof needs a silver coat (every 1~3 years) ~$100 and two hours.... Can't really see the shingles but for 17yo it's not bad. Ideally a new roof would engineer the flat part out.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion (and budget, and motivation) particularly since the photos are small and fuzzy. The hive mind can't help you. Try the magic 8 ball.

Answer (score 2):

Nail pop in a deck is not that big of a deal as long as you are not walking on that rolled roofing.

If the material is damaged at the nail some asphalt roof patch can seal it for a good 5 years.

I know prices have gone up and things are more expensive but 8 k for that small of a rolled roof? That sounds crazy high to me for the flat roof.

I would not worry about it for at least a few years then some asphalt patch in a tube for less than 10$ can give another 3-5 years.

This is based on what I can see.

Comment: So, 8k for the flat roof and shingles. Its about 10 squares sloped and 400 sq feet on the low slope

Comment: Nail pop is in the shingles

Comment: GMoney, maybe some better photos as I can not see a shingle where the arrows are pointing it looks more like rolled roofing. Nail pop with shingles can also be repaired diy but a warm day is advisable to help from breaking the shingles.